# Checkmarx fix for CGI_Stored_XSS Vulnerability

Tags: java, spring, xss, checkmarx, secure-coding

Checkmarx complains that there is a Unvalidated DB output. How to validate DB output in general?

Comment: Please share with us more information, like the code in the start and the end nodes in the result graph.

Answer (score 0):

In general you must encode the data you sent back to a client. Depending of your code, there is a lot of solutions.

See https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.md

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the contextual output (HTML, javascript, css, etc.), use escape methods such as [htmlEscape](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/HtmlUtils.html#htmlEscape-java.lang.String-) or [javaScriptEscape](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/JavaScriptUtils.html#javaScriptEscape-java.lang.String-) on your DB output